# google script create multiple folders by number list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]
when I create the lists, I want to automatically create the folder follow the list.
However, the scripts as below, it cannot create one by one folders.it shown me one folders called"E3:E8"
could anyone could help ?appreciate if any suggestion. thank you

```
function myFunction() {
  // Log the name of every folder in the user's Drive.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1D0DQVgTzPmDAWuqcOsOcz1t74jrePXJ7MWRhED5l_D0');
  var Sheet1=sheet.getSheetByName('Main Sheet')
  var sourceNAME= sheet.getRange('Main Sheet!E3:E8').getValues()
  //var sheet2=sheet.getSheetByName('Main Sheet')
 Logger.log(sourceNAME)
 //sheet2.getRange('Sheet7!E3:E8').setValues(sourceNAME)

const folderIterator = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName(sourceNAME);
  let targetFolder;
  if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    // When the folder exists
    targetFolder = folderIterator.next();
  } else {
    // When the folder doesn't exist
    targetFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(sourceNAME);
  }
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();

}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRod.png)

Comment: `create multiple folders by number list`, `when I create the lists, I want to automatically create the folder follow the list.` I'm sorry but I don't understand what this means. Since this is both a description of what you are trying to do, and a description of your problem, would you please edit your question to provide more detailed explanation and an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the folder name to be unique one, however, it shown mutiple duplicate folder name.eg.E3 column is "123",E4 is "1234",E5 is"123",E6 is"123",E7 is"1234",E8 is"1256", the folders will show 3folders called"123", 2 folders called"1234", 1foder called"1256".I just want to keep 1 foder called"123",1 called"1234",1 called"1256".Could you pls help me to check that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function createFoldersByNameInTheRoot() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1D0DQVgTzPmDAWuqcOsOcz1t74jrePXJ7MWRhED5l_D0');
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Main Sheet')
  var vs= ss.getRange('Main Sheet!E3:E8').getValues();
  let rt = DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    rt.createFolder(e);
  })
}
```

This will provide unique elements

```
function createFoldersByNameInTheRoot() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Main Sheet')
  var vs = [...new Set(sh1.getRange('E3:E8').getValues().flat())];
  let rt = DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  vs.forEach((e, i) => {
    rt.createFolder(e);
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, becauze "E3:E8"there are some duplicate number, how can I have the unique one？

Comment: I used the unique one, however, it still shown mutiple duplicate folder name.eg.E3 is "123",E4 is "1234",E5 is"123",E6 is"123",E7 is"1234",E8 is"1256", the folders will show 3folders called"123", 2 folders called"1234", 1foder called"1256".I just want to keep 1 foder called"123",1 called"1234",1 called"1256".Could you pls help me to check that ? thanks

Comment: Please provide a table of your data so that I can copy and paste it.  Note I will not follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: function createFoldersByNameInTheRoot() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1D0DQVgTzPmDAWuqcOsOcz1t74jrePXJ7MWRhED5l_D0');
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Mainsheet')
  var vs= ss.getRange('Mainsheet!H3:H10').getValues();
  let rt = DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    rt.createFolder(e);
  })}

Comment: Here is the the one, when I create folders, there will be create the lots duplicate folder called same name.

Comment: I've added on the picture to show my sheet, thanks

Comment: Learn how to post data in a table.

Comment: I don't even attempt to read functions pasted in comments

Comment: ```function createFoldersByNameInTheRoot() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1D0DQVgTzPmDAWuqcOsOcz1t74jrePXJ7MWRhED5l_D0');
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Mainsheet')
  var vs= ss.getRange('Mainsheet!H3:H10').getValues();
  let rt = DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {rt.createFolder(e);
  })}
```

Comment: please let me know if above works ?